# libusb-win32: Automated installation of a driver filter

Tags: windows, driver, libusb, filter-driver

I've faced a problem getting my libusb-w32 based program to detect devices.
The program has to detect digital cameras, and I need to automatically install driver filter for any new camera to be detected without any manual work. 
I've used install-filter i --class={6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F} , i. e. installing filter for MTP devices, and it seemed to work. But today I tried it on a clean machine and found out it actually only seemed that way. Tried install-filter with different parameters - no luck.
The only way I was able to detect devices at all was to use the inf-wizard.exe. It installed the driver, enabling my program to detect devices, but also disrupting the original Windows functionality for digital cameras. Then, I've uninstalled the libusb driver, installed the original windows driver back, executed install-filter i --class={6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}  - and the program is still able to detect devices.
The question is: how to automate the process so that any new camera is detected without any work required from a user?

**Update:**
I'll shorten the question. It seems that when I install a driver with inf-wizard.exe, it does something besides installing the driver itself. I need to know what, exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone has similar problem - the answer is here:

https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=749401313049992%40web78.yandex.ru&forum_name=libusb-win32-devel