# Does an HID device need libusbx Windows backend driver on Windows 7?

Tags: libusb

#### Current status:

I have developed some USB based device and have developed a driver on Linux using libusb. I am now porting the driver to Windows 7.

#### Device details

My device is a touch screen with two interfaces, one for the OS to communicate with the touch screen and the other for some vendor communication.

#### Old Stack Overflow post:

*[libusb_open returns 'LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED' on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350177)*

Here I was stuck with a problem that my libusb_open returned with an error. I learnt that I need Windows backend drivers. But I also learnt that it is for devices which are not recognised by the operating system.

#### Action taken

I tried installing a driver for my device using the [Zadig tool](https://github.com/libusbx/libusbx/wiki/Windows-Backend#wiki-How_to_use_libusbx_on_Windows), but I am not able to override the driver used by the OS with the new driver.

Do i really need a libusbx Windows backend driver for a device which has been identified and working well on windows 7? (The touch screen works perfect as a multitouch device)

What is the way forward as the device just can't be opened?

Comment: Have you tried using libusb-win32 in filter mode? Perhaps then it could handle opening your device - See http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki under "Filter Driver Installation"

Comment: Also, these might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010846/libusb-win32-automated-installation-of-a-driver-filter and http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=749401313049992%40web78.yandex.ru&forum_name=libusb-win32-devel

Answer (score 0):

If you really use libusbx then you should be able to at least open the device for sure.
Make sure you did not mess the default HID driver for your device while playing with Zadig tool. Go to Control Panel/Device Manager/Hid section (is your device listed there?), search your device and remove the driver. Then try again.