# How to get USB iManufacturer number?

Tags: c, usb, driver, libusb

Here's my C code:

```
int main()
{
    struct usb_bus *busses, *bus;
    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();

    busses = usb_get_busses();

    for (bus = busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
    {
        struct usb_device *dev;

        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next)
        {
            struct usb_device_descriptor *desc;

            desc = &(dev->descriptor);
            printf("idVendor/idProduct ID: %2.2x : %2.2x\n",desc->idVendor,desc->idProduct);

            if ((desc->idVendor == 0x2232) && (desc->idProduct == 0x6001))
            {
                printf("iManafacturer/iProduct ID: %04x  :%04x \n",desc->iManufacturer,desc->iProduct);
                //return dev;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return NULL;
}
```

After I complied the code (compile result), I can not get the iManufacturer number just like USBView result. I do not know how to get the iManufacturer (for example, NMGAAI00010200144W11111) like the USBView show.

How can I do this?

[image: Compile result]
[image: USBView result]

Answer (score 5):

The `iManufacturer` field of the device descriptor is the *index* of the manufacturer [string descriptor](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#StringDescriptors). The string is optional, an index of 0 means there is no string.

If you want the string, you can use [`static int libusb_get_string_descriptor()`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__desc.html#gab89c2119087308c6bfa6a4be30f39bc3) to get the string in unicode in any available language or the convenience method [`int libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii()`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__desc.html#gaf3f92d0a7465d49a5e61eb3f8689fae4) that gives you a C "string" in the first available language. You need a `libusb_device_handle` first.

Quick ugly example without any error checking :

```
libusb_open(dev, &dev_handle);
unsigned char manufacturer[200];
libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(dev_handle, desc->iManufacturer,
  manufacturer,200);
printf("%s \n", manufacturer);
```

In 0.1, [there are similar methods `usb_get_string()` and `usb_get_string_simple()`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/doc/ref.control.html).

Comment: The OP seems to be using libusb 0.1, but there should be something equivalent the OP can use in that version.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Added link. I stupidly thought he was just wrapping it in his own structures and methods, as I haven't used 0.1. It makes more sense now. :D

Comment: I use lusb0_usb.h and usb.h, I could not use libusb.h on Windows, How can I do?   I could not find the  manufacturer.

Comment: @user3579757 Google says [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) is based on libusb-0.1, this is what you are using, right ? The methods to request a string descriptor are those I added in my edit [`usb_get_string()` and `usb_get_string_simple()`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki/libusbwin32_documentation). They are used in the same way as the libusb-1.0 methods.

Comment: Dear Leiaz:
how do get the camera serial number without install inf-wizard.exe? 
If I install inf-wizard.exe, I can't use it as a webcam, if I didn't install the inf-wizard, I could not find the serial number of webcam.
how can I do?

Comment: @user3579757 This is a different question, and should be asked separately. Perhaps [read this one first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010846/libusb-win32-automated-installation-of-a-driver-filter) ? And perhaps search about "filter driver" ? I don't use Windows, so I don't know more about it.

Comment: Where did you get the length of 200 from?

Comment: How do you get the string descriptor WITHOUT a handle to the device? For example, I need to get a string descriptor for every device I have connected (so I can look at the manufacturer string, not just the manufacturer value). To use `get_string_descriptor_ascii()` I need a device HANDLE, which only can be obtained by opening a device, but I can't open a device that's already in use.